# R coding regarding creating empty matrix to store matrixes

Tags: wordpress

My.LDA<-function(x,y,X1){
m<-matrix(,length(y),2)

For (i in 1:max(y)){

m[i]<- X[Y==i,]
}

For the above coding, how do I go above creating an empty matrix to store all these matrix that is loop out from the loop?

i is the different classes such that the matrices will be differentiate out of the big matrices. How can I store them then?